# POST http://localhost:3001/[object%20Promise] 404 (Not Found) React Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here is my code to send data to the server but I always get this Error.

```
let data = {
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "language": "en",
        "country": "en",
        "istestentry": false
    };

    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    let encodedData = encodeURIComponent(jsonData);
    let url = "https://example.org/b/receiver/external";
    let fetchUrl = url + "?datajsonstr=" + encodedData + "&_=" + (new Date()).valueOf();
    let datafetch = fetch(fetchUrl);

    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState('');

    async function fetchData(){
        const  {data} = await axios.post(
            datafetch
        )
        setFetchedData(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetchData()
};
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: you have to make axios.get request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send a promise instead of a stringified data. `let datafetch = fetch(fetchUrl);` gives you a promise. Also sending data through params is done with `get` requests. So I assume that you may need to make a `get` request:

```
let fetchUrl = url + "?datajsonstr=" + encodedData + "&_=" + (new Date()).valueOf();

const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState('');

async function fetchData(){
    const  {data} = await axios.get(fetchUrl)
    setFetchedData(data)
}
```

(P.S. `get` or `post` depends on how your api handles requests. You can choose the correct one)

Comment: I think the answer is also correct, but I haven't used Axios anymore. @ABDULLOKH MUKHAMMADJONOV

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.
if you don't want to use Axios, you can solve it also like this.

const [dataDone, setDataDone] = useState(false);

```
useEffect(() => {
    let data = {
        "email": "test@gmail.at",
        "language": "de",
        "country": "de",
        "istestentry": false
    };

    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    let encodedData = encodeURIComponent(jsonData);
    let url = "https://org.com;
    let fetchUrl = url + "?datajsonstr=" + encodedData + "&_=" + (new 
    Date()).valueOf();
    let datafetch = fetch(fetchUrl);

    datafetch.then(data => {
        setDataDone(true)
    })
}, [])
```